# ClangFormat incorrect block indentation

Tags: javascript, clang-format

The closing bracket of the if statement is incorrectly indented:

```
if (1) {
  2;
  }
var x = 3;
```

Placing a semicolon after the closing bracket seems to solve the problem, but it is undesirable.

The command line options are `clang-format -style="{Language: JavaScript}" test.js`.

I went through the [style options documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) to no avail. Is that a bug, or is there a way to configure the formatter to correctly indent the block?